# Get button attributes using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making slider. There is the main container and some `DIVs` inside it, each     `DIV` is one slide and contains some `buttons`.

Buttons have  event that slides to the next `DIV` and hides all the `buttons` from other `DIVs` with the same id as the clicked one (id is random number from 1 to 10). I don't know how to finish slide function and hide these `buttons`.

I know I can get clicked `button` id by using `this` property, but I don't know how to get the `button` from next `DIV` by id.

I just need to know what should i put instead of *** in if statement and I can finish the rest. For loop is not the problem

```
    for (var i=1;i<maxLevel+1; i++){
    var divId = i.toString()
    var div = $("<div></div>").attr({
        id:divId,
     });
    for (var j=0; j<classificationsNumber;j++){
        if(accountArray[j].ad_level===i){
            var classificationButton=$('<input/>').attr({
                type: "button",
                id: Math.round( Math.random()*10),
                value: accountArray[j].ad_name
            }).bind("click", function(){
                // Go to the next slide
                $(".slider").diyslider("move", "back");

             //PROBLEM: find the buttons from next div have the same id as the clicked one  
             //for(...){
             //    if (***) {$('#'+id).css("display","none")}}

            }); 
            div.append(classificationButton);

        }            

        }
        mainContainer.prepend(div);
    }
```

Comment: why set the id as a random number? Why not set it is a known number like `j`? Then you know both the previous and the next ids?

Comment: The task is defined like that. This is just part of the program.

Comment: You can also use .next method for your current div block if your slides goes consecutive in HTML. For example: $("#slide1").next().find("button").hide(). 
https://api.jquery.com/next/

Also you can check .closest method.
https://api.jquery.com/closest/